# Is there any proof that the order of CSS is relevant?

Tags: html, css, safari, mozilla

Does it matter if my CSS orders global (parent) styles at the end of the other styles? Personally, I have a theory that all styles in a style tag are parsed first and processed after (setting up inheritance after). That's only a theory and it could be different in different browsers. If all the CSS is processed *after* the style tag is parse then the order should not matter.

For example is exhibit **B** faster than exhibit **A**? Can you prove it? Exhibit B has global styles (*, HTML, Body) ordered at the beginning.

**Exhibit A:**

```
<style>

    #VGroup2210  {
        position:absolute;
        top:35px;
        left:25px;
        overflow:visible;
        text-align:left;
    }

    #Label2211  {
        position:relative;
        vertical-align:top;
        margin-bottom:12px;
        display:block;
        font-weight:bold;
        margin-top:-0.2em;
    }

    #Label2212  {
        position:relative;
        vertical-align:top;
        margin-bottom:12px;
        display:block;
        margin-top:-0.2em;
    }

    #Label2213  {
        position:relative;
        vertical-align:top;
        margin-bottom:12px;
        display:block;
        margin-top:-0.2em;
    }

    #Label2214  {
        position:relative;
        vertical-align:top;
        margin-bottom:12px;
        display:block;
        margin-top:-0.2em;
    }

    #Label2215  {
        position:relative;
        vertical-align:top;
        margin-bottom:12px;
        display:block;
        margin-top:-0.2em;
    }

    #Label2216  {
        position:relative;
        vertical-align:top;
        margin-bottom:12px;
        display:block;
        margin-top:-0.2em;
    }

    #Label2217  {
        position:relative;
        vertical-align:top;
        margin-bottom:12px;
        display:block;
        margin-top:-0.2em;
    }

    #Label2218  {
        position:relative;
        vertical-align:top;
        margin-bottom:12px;
        display:block;
        margin-top:-0.2em;
    }

    #Label2219  {
        position:relative;
        vertical-align:top;
        margin-bottom:12px;
        display:block;
        margin-top:-0.2em;
    }

    #Label2220  {
        position:relative;
        vertical-align:top;
        margin-bottom:12px;
        display:block;
        margin-top:-0.2em;
    }

    #Label2221  {
        position:relative;
        vertical-align:top;
        margin-bottom:12px;
        display:block;
        margin-top:-0.2em;
    }

    #Label2222  {
        position:relative;
        vertical-align:top;
        margin-bottom:12px;
        display:block;
        margin-top:-0.2em;
    }

    #Label2223  {
        position:relative;
        vertical-align:top;
        display:block;
        margin-top:-0.2em;
    }

    #BorderContainer2224  {
        position:absolute;
        top:30px;
        left:100px;
        width:562px;
        height:50px;
        display:inline-block;
        background-color:rgba(255,255,255,1);
        border-style:solid;
        border-width:1px;
        border-color:#696969;
        border-radius:0px;
    }

    #HGroup2229  {
        position:absolute;
        top:30px;
        left:101px;
        min-width:20px;
        min-height:20px;
        height:50px;
        display:inline-block;
        overflow:visible;
        text-align:left;
    }

    #Label2230  {
        position:relative;
        display:inline-block;
        vertical-align:middle;
        margin-right:8px;
        margin-top:-0.2em;
    }

    #Label2231  {
        position:relative;
        display:inline-block;
        vertical-align:middle;
        margin-right:8px;
        margin-top:-0.2em;
    }

    #Label2232  {
        position:relative;
        display:inline-block;
        vertical-align:middle;
        margin-right:8px;
        margin-top:-0.2em;
    }

    #Label2233  {
        position:relative;
        display:inline-block;
        vertical-align:middle;
        margin-right:8px;
        margin-top:-0.2em;
    }

    #Label2234  {
        position:relative;
        display:inline-block;
        vertical-align:middle;
        margin-right:8px;
        margin-top:-0.2em;
    }

    #Label2235  {
        position:relative;
        display:inline-block;
        vertical-align:middle;
        margin-right:8px;
        margin-top:-0.2em;
    }

    #Label2236  {
        position:relative;
        display:inline-block;
        vertical-align:middle;
        margin-right:8px;
        margin-top:-0.2em;
    }

    #Label2237  {
        position:relative;
        display:inline-block;
        vertical-align:middle;
        margin-right:8px;
        margin-top:-0.2em;
    }

    #Label2238  {
        position:relative;
        display:inline-block;
        vertical-align:middle;
        margin-top:-0.2em;
    }

    #HGroup2239  {
        position:absolute;
        top:166px;
        left:209px;
        min-width:20px;
        min-height:20px;
        overflow:visible;
        text-align:left;
    }

    #Label2240  {
        position:relative;
        display:inline-block;
        vertical-align:middle;
        margin-right:2px;
        font-weight:bold;
        margin-top:-0.2em;
    }

    #BorderContainer2241  {
        position:relative;
        display:inline-block;
        vertical-align:middle;
        margin-right:2px;
        width:300px;
        height:250px;
        display:inline-block;
        background-color:rgba(255,255,255,1);
        border-style:solid;
        border-width:1px;
        border-color:#696969;
        border-radius:0px;
        font-size:9px;
    }

    #Label2246  {
        position:absolute;
        top:20px;
        left:20px;
        margin-top:-0.2em;
    }

    #Label2248  {
        position:absolute;
        top:20px;
        display:table;
        left:50%;
        transform:translateX(-50%);
        -webkit-transform:translateX(-50%);
        -ms-transform:translateX(-50%);
        margin-top:-0.2em;
    }

    #Label2249  {
        position:absolute;
        top:20px;
        right:20px;
        margin-top:-0.2em;
    }

    #Label2250  {
        position:absolute;
        display:table;
        top:50%;
        transform:translateY(-50%);
        -webkit-transform:translateY(-50%);
        -ms-transform:translateY(-50%);
        left:20px;
        margin-top:-0.2em;
    }

    #Label2251  {
        position:absolute;
        display:table;
        top:50%;
        transform:translateY(-50%);
        -webkit-transform:translateY(-50%);
        -ms-transform:translateY(-50%);
        right:20px;
        margin-top:-0.2em;
    }

    #Label2252  {
        position:absolute;
        bottom:20px;
        left:20px;
        margin-top:-0.2em;
    }

    #Label2253  {
        position:absolute;
        bottom:20px;
        display:table;
        left:50%;
        transform:translateX(-50%);
        -webkit-transform:translateX(-50%);
        -ms-transform:translateX(-50%);
        margin-top:-0.2em;
    }

    #Label2254  {
        position:absolute;
        bottom:20px;
        right:20px;
        margin-top:-0.2em;
    }

    #Label2255  {
        position:absolute;
        display:table;
        top:50%;
        left:50%;
        transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
        -webkit-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
        -ms-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
        margin-top:-0.2em;
    }

    #Label2256  {
        position:relative;
        display:inline-block;
        vertical-align:middle;
        font-weight:bold;
        margin-top:-0.2em;
    }

    /* Global styles */

    *, *:before, *:after {
        -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
        -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
        box-sizing:border-box;
    }

    html, body {
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }

    body {
        font-family:Verdana;
        font-weight:normal;
        font-size:12px;
    }
</style>
```

**Exhibit B:**

```
<style>

    /* Global styles */

    *, *:before, *:after {
        -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
        -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
        box-sizing:border-box;
    }

    html, body {
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }

    body {
        font-family:Verdana;
        font-weight:normal;
        font-size:12px;
    }

    #VGroup2210  {
        position:absolute;
        top:35px;
        left:25px;
        overflow:visible;
        text-align:left;
    }

    #Label2211  {
        position:relative;
        vertical-align:top;
        margin-bottom:12px;
        display:block;
        font-weight:bold;
        margin-top:-0.2em;
    }

    #Label2212  {
        position:relative;
        vertical-align:top;
        margin-bottom:12px;
        display:block;
        margin-top:-0.2em;
    }

    #Label2213  {
        position:relative;
        vertical-align:top;
        margin-bottom:12px;
        display:block;
        margin-top:-0.2em;
    }

    #Label2214  {
        position:relative;
        vertical-align:top;
        margin-bottom:12px;
        display:block;
        margin-top:-0.2em;
    }

    #Label2215  {
        position:relative;
        vertical-align:top;
        margin-bottom:12px;
        display:block;
        margin-top:-0.2em;
    }

    #Label2216  {
        position:relative;
        vertical-align:top;
        margin-bottom:12px;
        display:block;
        margin-top:-0.2em;
    }

    #Label2217  {
        position:relative;
        vertical-align:top;
        margin-bottom:12px;
        display:block;
        margin-top:-0.2em;
    }

    #Label2218  {
        position:relative;
        vertical-align:top;
        margin-bottom:12px;
        display:block;
        margin-top:-0.2em;
    }

    #Label2219  {
        position:relative;
        vertical-align:top;
        margin-bottom:12px;
        display:block;
        margin-top:-0.2em;
    }

    #Label2220  {
        position:relative;
        vertical-align:top;
        margin-bottom:12px;
        display:block;
        margin-top:-0.2em;
    }

    #Label2221  {
        position:relative;
        vertical-align:top;
        margin-bottom:12px;
        display:block;
        margin-top:-0.2em;
    }

    #Label2222  {
        position:relative;
        vertical-align:top;
        margin-bottom:12px;
        display:block;
        margin-top:-0.2em;
    }

    #Label2223  {
        position:relative;
        vertical-align:top;
        display:block;
        margin-top:-0.2em;
    }

    #BorderContainer2224  {
        position:absolute;
        top:30px;
        left:100px;
        width:562px;
        height:50px;
        display:inline-block;
        background-color:rgba(255,255,255,1);
        border-style:solid;
        border-width:1px;
        border-color:#696969;
        border-radius:0px;
    }

    #HGroup2229  {
        position:absolute;
        top:30px;
        left:101px;
        min-width:20px;
        min-height:20px;
        height:50px;
        display:inline-block;
        overflow:visible;
        text-align:left;
    }

    #Label2230  {
        position:relative;
        display:inline-block;
        vertical-align:middle;
        margin-right:8px;
        margin-top:-0.2em;
    }

    #Label2231  {
        position:relative;
        display:inline-block;
        vertical-align:middle;
        margin-right:8px;
        margin-top:-0.2em;
    }

    #Label2232  {
        position:relative;
        display:inline-block;
        vertical-align:middle;
        margin-right:8px;
        margin-top:-0.2em;
    }

    #Label2233  {
        position:relative;
        display:inline-block;
        vertical-align:middle;
        margin-right:8px;
        margin-top:-0.2em;
    }

    #Label2234  {
        position:relative;
        display:inline-block;
        vertical-align:middle;
        margin-right:8px;
        margin-top:-0.2em;
    }

    #Label2235  {
        position:relative;
        display:inline-block;
        vertical-align:middle;
        margin-right:8px;
        margin-top:-0.2em;
    }

    #Label2236  {
        position:relative;
        display:inline-block;
        vertical-align:middle;
        margin-right:8px;
        margin-top:-0.2em;
    }

    #Label2237  {
        position:relative;
        display:inline-block;
        vertical-align:middle;
        margin-right:8px;
        margin-top:-0.2em;
    }

    #Label2238  {
        position:relative;
        display:inline-block;
        vertical-align:middle;
        margin-top:-0.2em;
    }

    #HGroup2239  {
        position:absolute;
        top:166px;
        left:209px;
        min-width:20px;
        min-height:20px;
        overflow:visible;
        text-align:left;
    }

    #Label2240  {
        position:relative;
        display:inline-block;
        vertical-align:middle;
        margin-right:2px;
        font-weight:bold;
        margin-top:-0.2em;
    }

    #BorderContainer2241  {
        position:relative;
        display:inline-block;
        vertical-align:middle;
        margin-right:2px;
        width:300px;
        height:250px;
        display:inline-block;
        background-color:rgba(255,255,255,1);
        border-style:solid;
        border-width:1px;
        border-color:#696969;
        border-radius:0px;
        font-size:9px;
    }

    #Label2246  {
        position:absolute;
        top:20px;
        left:20px;
        margin-top:-0.2em;
    }

    #Label2248  {
        position:absolute;
        top:20px;
        display:table;
        left:50%;
        transform:translateX(-50%);
        -webkit-transform:translateX(-50%);
        -ms-transform:translateX(-50%);
        margin-top:-0.2em;
    }

    #Label2249  {
        position:absolute;
        top:20px;
        right:20px;
        margin-top:-0.2em;
    }

    #Label2250  {
        position:absolute;
        display:table;
        top:50%;
        transform:translateY(-50%);
        -webkit-transform:translateY(-50%);
        -ms-transform:translateY(-50%);
        left:20px;
        margin-top:-0.2em;
    }

    #Label2251  {
        position:absolute;
        display:table;
        top:50%;
        transform:translateY(-50%);
        -webkit-transform:translateY(-50%);
        -ms-transform:translateY(-50%);
        right:20px;
        margin-top:-0.2em;
    }

    #Label2252  {
        position:absolute;
        bottom:20px;
        left:20px;
        margin-top:-0.2em;
    }

    #Label2253  {
        position:absolute;
        bottom:20px;
        display:table;
        left:50%;
        transform:translateX(-50%);
        -webkit-transform:translateX(-50%);
        -ms-transform:translateX(-50%);
        margin-top:-0.2em;
    }

    #Label2254  {
        position:absolute;
        bottom:20px;
        right:20px;
        margin-top:-0.2em;
    }

    #Label2255  {
        position:absolute;
        display:table;
        top:50%;
        left:50%;
        transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
        -webkit-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
        -ms-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
        margin-top:-0.2em;
    }

    #Label2256  {
        position:relative;
        display:inline-block;
        vertical-align:middle;
        font-weight:bold;
        margin-top:-0.2em;
    }

</style>
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="VGroup2210">
    <span id="Label2211">Left</span>
    <span id="Label2212">Apple</span>
    <span id="Label2213">Orange</span>
    <span id="Label2214">Banana</span>
    <span id="Label2215">Grape</span>
    <span id="Label2216">Cherry</span>
    <span id="Label2217">Mango</span>
    <span id="Label2218">Kiwi</span>
    <span id="Label2219">Pineapple</span>
    <span id="Label2220">Strawberry</span>
    <span id="Label2221">Blueberry</span>
    <span id="Label2222">Raspberry</span>
    <span id="Label2223">Orange</span>
</div>
<div id="BorderContainer2224">&#160;
</div >
<div id="HGroup2229">
    <span id="Label2230">Apple</span>
    <span id="Label2231">Orange</span>
    <span id="Label2232">Banana</span>
    <span id="Label2233">Grape</span>
    <span id="Label2234">Cherry</span>
    <span id="Label2235">Mango</span>
    <span id="Label2236">Kiwi</span>
    <span id="Label2237">Pineapple</span>
    <span id="Label2238">Strawberry</span>
    <span style='display:inline-block;height:100%;width:0;vertical-align:middle;'></span>
</div>
<div id="HGroup2239">
    <span id="Label2240">Left</span>
    <div id="BorderContainer2241">
        <span id="Label2246">Top Left</span>
        <span id="Label2248">Top Centered</span>
        <span id="Label2249">Top Right</span>
        <span id="Label2250">Left Center</span>
        <span id="Label2251">Right Center</span>
        <span id="Label2252">Bottom Left</span>
        <span id="Label2253">Bottom Centered</span>
        <span id="Label2254">Bottom Right</span>
        <span id="Label2255">Center</span>
    </div >
    <span id="Label2256">Right</span>
    <span style='display:inline-block;height:100%;width:0;vertical-align:middle;'></span>
</div>
```

Is it the same across browsers?

Comment: Thanks for all the down votes guys! You're all really great.

Answer (score 1):

after some testing, I've come to the conclusion that, on my pc, exibit A takes an average of 7 ms to load, and exibit B 17 ms, both of these numbers are an average of 10 runs per exibit and might not be the same on your device, but, I guess it does matter what way you declade your CSS

Comment: Thanks for testing. I was told that Exhibit B would be faster because all the global styles were at the beginning. This is an interesting finding. What browser if I may ask?

Comment: currently at work, so I am being forced to use internet explorer 11, I used the microsoft edge debug